# How to get the data from same table by different conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have below data in my `ColorAssign` table;

```
| PKID | Name    | Type | HasAssigned |
| 11   | Red     | 1    | True        |
| 12   | Blue    | 2    | False       |
| 13   | Yellow  | 3    | False       |
| 14   | Red1    | 1    | False       |
| 15   | Yellow1 | 3    | True        |
| 16   | Blue1   | 2    | False       |
```

Note in this above table I have color types in type field and assign status in `HasAssigned` field also with different primary keys with different names (can be same name - but type is the identifier to find the actual color).

My goal is to get the data as the condition:-

*Find the records with the color type with `Hasassigned = true` or if no records for the type has true. Then type with `Hasassigned = false` of color type. So my resultset would be*;

```
| 11   | Red     | 1    | True        |
| 12   | Blue    | 2    | False       |
| 15   | Yellow1 | 3    | True        |
| 16   | Blue1   | 2    | False       |
```

What are all the ways we can do this, with a focus on optimization?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want all rows with HasAssigned='True'

**AND**

all rows where HasAssigned='False' where there does not exist a row for that same type that is also HasAssigned='True'

If that is what you want, I think this query will give you that answer:

```
DECLARE @ColorAssignTable TABLE (
    PKID INT
    ,NAME VARCHAR(30)
    ,Type INT
    ,HasAssigned VARCHAR(10)
    )
insert into @ColorAssignTable(PKID,Name,Type,HasAssigned) values
(11,'Red',1,'True'),
(12,'Blue',2,'False'),
(13,'Yellow',3,'False'),
(14,'Red1',1,'False'),
(15,'Yellow1',3,'True'),
(16,'Blue1',2,'False')

SELECT *
FROM @ColorAssignTable
WHERE HasAssigned = 'True'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM @ColorAssignTable a
WHERE HasAssigned = 'False'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM @ColorAssignTable
        WHERE type = a.type
            AND HasAssigned = 'True'
        )
Order by PKID
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this way and i could do this;

> select * from ColorAssign ci where   (ci.HasAssigned = 'True'  OR  NOT
>   EXISTS(select 1 from ColorAssign sc where sc.Type = ci.Type AND
>   sc.HasAssigned = 'True' )  )